How to get a slanted and curly “greater or equal than” symbol?
It is possible to use \geqslant to obtain a slanted greater or equal than symbol, \succ to obtain a curly greater or equal than symbol, and \succeq to obtain a curly greater or equal than symbol. I am wondering whether it is possible to obtain a curly and slanted greater or equal than symbol.
Consider the following MWE:
\documentclass[]{article}

% PACKAGES LOADING

\usepackage[]{amssymb}

\begin{document}

$\geqslant$

$\succ$

$\succeq$

\end{document}

Which produces these three symbols:

The symbol I’m looking for would look like this:

If such a symbol exists, how do I obtain it?

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

$
\preccurlyeq
\succcurlyeq
\curlyeqprec
\curlyeqsucc
$

\end{document}



Thank you! I was looking for it here (https://oeis.org/wiki/List_of_LaTeX_mathematical_symbols), but couldn’t find it.

http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf
